# Remove DataFrame rows that doesn't contain string from another DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Let's say I have two spark DataFrames df1 and df2:

```
Text:            Date:

LongStringID1    2019-01-01
LongStringID2    2019-01-01
LongStringID3    2019-01-01
LongID4String    2019-01-01


ID:

ID2
ID4
```

In that case, I would like to get a new DF with records that contain text from df2:

```
Text:            Date:

LongStringID2    2019-01-01
LongID4String    2019-01-01
```

How to implement this functionality in Scala?

Comment: What have you tried? What output are you getting? Where are you stuck? Please edit your post and show us your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

df1 setup:

`val df1 = Seq(("LongStringID1","2019-01-01"),("LongStringID2","2019-02-01"),      ("LongID4String","2019-01-01"),("LongID39String","2019-02-01")).toDF("text","dt")`

`df1.registerTempTable("tbl_df1")`

df2 setup:

`val df2 = Seq(("ID2"),("ID3")).toDF("id")`
`df2.registerTempTable("tbl_df2")`

Logic :

`spark.sql("select t1.* from tbl_df1 t1 inner join tbl_df2 t2 where t2.id=regexp_extract(t1.text,'ID*[\\\\d]+',0)").show`

Comment: Thank you for your help. Can you tell me what if ID from df2 will be something different, i.e. random word?

Comment: basically depending on your data, you have to fine tune the regex expressions to match it with df1 text in the join condition. Thanks!